# strtok() problem getting the first token of a string

Tags: c, strtok

The following code fails to get me the first token of the string:

```
char *p1;
char array[100];
strcpy(array, "ANY STRING WOULD DO");
p1 = strtok(array, " ");
p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
p1 = strtok(array, " ");
p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");

printf("%c", p1);
```

Comment: Next time please use code formatting. I've done it this time for you.

Comment: the program runs but terminates automatically, but if i remove the second p1 = strtok(NULL, " "); it runs perfectly

Comment: oops. sorry. i forgot to use it.

Answer (score 5):

`strtok()` actually replaces the delimiters with a literal '\0' - in effect writing over your original string. The second time you call `strtok(array, "");`, `array` now looks like

ANY'\0'STRING'\0'WOULD DO

(e.g. if you were to print the string, you'd just see "ANY")

Since strtok doesn't go beyond the end of a string, you'll only get the one token the second time around, and the call to `strtok(NULL, " ");` returns `NULL`. To overcome your problem, you need to either copy the string into another location for the second set of operations, or save a temporary string pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the example given here: [MSDN: strtok, wcstok, _mbstok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
char *p1;
char array[100];
strcpy(array, "ANY STRING WOULD DO");
p1 = strtok(array, " ");
p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(array, "ANY STRING WOULD DO");
p1 = strtok(array, " ");

printf("%s", p1);
```

strtok modifies the string it is passed so if you want to re-parse it you need to copy it again.

If you just want to keep the tokens, just copy the pointers.

Comment: It wouldn't. Because you're passing a string literal to `strtok`, and it will want to modify that.

Comment: nope... I'm passing a copy, just like the original code, the literal is the delimiter string and strtok won't change that.

Comment: heh ... my eyes deceived me heh ... For some reason I thought the `"ANY STRING WOULD DO"` string literal was passed to strtok directly - ignore me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `strtok` modifies the string by placing `'\0'` characters after every token.

So, when you try tokenizing the same string again, you're really tokenizing the first token only.

This will have as a result that the second `p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");` will return `NULL`, and when you then try to print p1, it'll try to dereference `NULL`, and probably fail.

Note btw, that you need to use `"%s"` instead of `"%c"`, because you're printing a string, not a character.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` actually modifies the string you are looking for tokens in by adding zero-terminator characters ('\0') to it when it finds the end of a token. So after iterating through it, it is no longer a continuous string in memory anymore. This is why you can not start again at the beginning and re-parse the string for tokens.

You probably have two choices:

- make a *copy* of the string first and tokenise that instead

  ```
  char *p1; char array[100]; strcpy(array, "ANY STRING WOULD DO");

  char tmp[100];
  strcpy( tmp, array );
  p1 = strtok(tmp, " ");
  p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");

  strcpy( tmp, array );
  p1 = strtok(tmp, " ");
  p1 = strtok(NULL, " ");

  printf("%c", p1);
  ```
- or you could keep an array of pointers to the separate tokens as you find them and re-use the array, rather than re-calling `strtok()`.